# Display Elastic vector tiles with Deck.gl

Tags: elasticsearch, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, mbtiles

I'm trying to use Deck.gl with [MVTLayer](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/mvt-layer) to display some [Elastic vector tiles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-vector-tile-api.html).

**Using *maplibre-gl***

So far, I've been able to make it work using the [maplibre-gl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maplibre-gl) library:

```js
map.addSource(sourceName, {
  'type': 'vector',
  'tiles': [
      `http://localhost:8099/tile?index=mobile-ping-test-2-2024&geometry=geo&renderMethod=hits&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`
  ],
  'minzoom': 0,
  'maxzoom': 24
});

// Elasticsearch vector tile API returns tiles with 3 layers
// "hits": Contains a feature for each document (hit) matching search criteria.
// "aggs": Contains a feature for each bucket returned from geotile_grid or geohex_grid aggregation.
// "meta": Contains a single feature with meta data about the feature properties.
// 
// 'vector' layer specification requires "source-layer" property. This property identifies the layer to display from the tile.
const sourceLayer = "hits";     // not arbitrary value - must be layer name provided from tile

map.addLayer(
  {
      'id': 'layer_point',
      'type': 'circle',
      'source': 'es_mvt', // arbitrary value, you can use any string you like
      'source-layer': sourceLayer,
      'paint': {
          'circle-radius': 4,
          'circle-color': 'green',
          'circle-opacity': 0.5,
          'circle-stroke-color': 'rgb(255,0,0)',
          'circle-stroke-opacity': 1,
          'circle-stroke-width': 1,
      }
  }
);

map.setFilter(circleStyle, [
  'any',
  ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'Point'],
  ['==', ['geometry-type'], 'MultiPoint'],
]);
```

[image: Result with maplibre-gl]

**Using *mapbox-gl* and *Deck.gl***

But, when I'm trying to reproduce the same with Deck.gl:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@^8.4.0/dist.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://libs.cartocdn.com/mapbox-gl/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://libs.cartocdn.com/mapbox-gl/v1.13.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    const deckgl = new deck.DeckGL({
        container: 'map',
        mapStyle: 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/dark-matter-gl-style/style.json',
        initialViewState: {
          latitude: 40.4165,
          longitude: -3.70256,
          zoom: 5,
        },
        controller: true,
        layers: [
        new deck.MVTLayer({
          data: 'http://localhost:8099/tile?index=mobile-ping-test-2-2024&geometry=geo&renderMethod=hits&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}.mvt',
          pointType: 'circle',
          getFillColor: [255,0,0],
          lineWidthMinPixels: 1
        })
        ],
      });
  </script>
</html>
```

This is what I get:
[image: only deck.gl]

I can even see the points if I zoom the map, but still have some tiles totally in red:
[image]

I'm using same local Tiles Server in both cases, I've made sure that the MVT responses that I get are correct, etc.

**¿What am I missing to make it work with Deck.gl?**